# Mount type always set to none

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, ext4

Wish you a good day!

I want to mount a folder with type ntfs or ext2 or ext4 in order to set permissions for files in that.

This is how I did:

```
tudinh@Acoustic:~$ sudo mount --bind -v -t ext2 -o umask=0022,gid=1004,uid=1001 /media/tudinh/Data/Downloads/oracledb /oracledb
```

And this is the results, type set to `none` instead of `ext4`:

```
/media/tudinh/Data/Downloads/oracledb on /oracledb type none (rw,bind,umask=0022,gid=1004,uid=1001)
```

Given that:

- I set `-o umask=0022,gid=1004,uid=1001` because I want to grant all permission to user 1001 and group 1004. Pls tell me if this is not correct.
- `/media/tudinh/Data/Downloads/oracledb` is a folder in NTFS partition. (yes, I install Ubuntu along with Windows)
- `/oracledb` is the mount point I created in `/` ext4 partition

My final purpose is to grant full permissions to user 1001 and group 1004 to all files within `/media/tudinh/Data/Downloads/oracledb`

Comment: You can't mount an NTFS partition as ext2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bind mount always has type `none`. If you don't want type `none`, don't use bind mounts. Using a bind mount doesn't change permissions or ownerships.

Comment: No doubt I can't do that, thanks so much for your answer. But if I mount without `--bind`, I will receive error `Failed to mount /media/tudinh/Data/Downloads/oracledb': Is a directory`. So what should I do to mount the folder, and grant all permissions?

Comment: @BimBim, you mount a *device*, not a folder. The bind mount is really a sophisticated case of a symlink... the permissions, ownerships etc *capabilities* are the ones of the underlying filesystem, you can't change them. If you want to apply the `uid`,`gid` or similar things, you have to apply that to the whole NTFS device when you first mount it.